# Can't get BITMAPINFOHEADER data to display odd width bmp images correctly

Tags: winapi, bitmap

I am trying to display a 24-bit uncompressed bitmap with an odd width using standard Win32 API calls, but it seems like I have a stride problem.

According to the msdn:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

"For uncompressed RGB formats, the minimum stride is always the image width in bytes, rounded up to the nearest DWORD. You can use the following formula to calculate the stride:

stride = ((((biWidth * biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3)"

but this simply does not work for me and below is is the code:

```
void Init()
{
    pImage = ReadBMP("data\\bird.bmp");
    size_t imgSize = pImage->width * pImage->height * 3;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;
    bmih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmih.biBitCount = 24;
    // This is probably where the bug is
    LONG stride = ((((pImage->width * bmih.biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3);
    //bmih.biWidth = pImage->width;
    bmih.biWidth = stride;
    bmih.biHeight = -((LONG)pImage->height);
    bmih.biPlanes = 1;
    bmih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmih.biSizeImage = 0;
    bmih.biXPelsPerMeter = 1;
    bmih.biYPelsPerMeter = 1;
    bmih.biClrUsed = 0;
    bmih.biClrImportant = 0;

    BITMAPINFO dbmi;
    ZeroMemory(&dbmi, sizeof(dbmi));
    dbmi.bmiHeader = bmih;
    dbmi.bmiColors->rgbBlue = 0;
    dbmi.bmiColors->rgbGreen = 0;
    dbmi.bmiColors->rgbRed = 0;
    dbmi.bmiColors->rgbReserved = 0;

    HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);

    mTestBMP = CreateDIBitmap(hdc,
        &bmih,
        CBM_INIT,
        pImage->pSrc,
        &dbmi,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);
}
```

and here the drawing fuction

```
RawBMP *pImage;
HBITMAP mTestBMP;
void UpdateScreen(HDC srcHDC)
{
    if (pImage != nullptr && mTestBMP != 0x00)
    {
        HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(srcHDC);
        SelectObject(hdc, mTestBMP);
        BitBlt(srcHDC,
            0,  // x
            0,  // y
            // I tried passing the stride here and it did not work either
            pImage->width, // width of the image
            pImage->height, // height
            hdc,
            0,   // x and
            0,   // y of upper left corner
            SRCCOPY);
        DeleteDC(hdc);
    }
}
```

If I pass the original image width (odd number) instead of the stride

```
LONG stride = ((((pImage->width * bmih.biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3);
//bmih.biWidth = stride;
bmih.biWidth = pImage->width;
```

the picture looks skewed, below shows the differences:

[image]

and if I pass the stride according to msdn, then nothing shows up because the stride is too large.

any clues? Thank you!

Comment: It's been a while, but as I recall the only time stride comes into play is when you're accessing the bitmap bits directly. The `BitmapInfoHeader.biWidth` field is the number of pixels, *not* the number of bytes per scan line. I would recommend setting `bmih.biWidth = pImage->width;`, and calling `BitBlt` with the `pImage->width`.

Comment: @JimMischel I did originally set the biWith and the BitBlt with the image width in pixels, but this is exactly how the bird picture show ups above, i.e. Skewed to the side.

Comment: Are you sure that the `pImage->pSrc` has the correct padding bytes? That's where `CreateDiBitmap` is getting the data to populate the image. If it doesn't have the correct padding, things won't work.

Comment: @JimMischel I don't understand the pImage->pSrc is just pointing to the raw 24-bit data. The width of the image is an odd number. Should the raw data be padded with extra bytes? I don't think there is any padding on the raw image. I would not expect I have to pad the raw data.

Comment: `biWidth` doesn't need to be rounded up, the buffer size you allocate for the bitmap does. Each scan line starts at `(row * stride)` bytes into the buffer. If you have raw 24 bit data that's not padded to DWORD-aligned rows then you'll need to allocate a new buffer and copy each row in individually.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thx Jonathan that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

thanks Jonathan for the solution. I need to copy row by row with the proper padding for odd width images. More or less the code for 24-bit uncompressed images:

```
const uint32_t bitCount = 24;
LONG strideInBytes;

// if the width is odd, then we need to add padding
if (width & 0x1)
{
    strideInBytes = ((((width * bitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3);
}
else
{
    strideInBytes = width * 3;
}

// allocate the new buffer
unsigned char *pBuffer = new unsigned char[strideInBytes * height];
memset(pBuffer, 0xaa, strideInBytes * height);

// Copy row by row
for (uint32_t yy = 0; yy < height; yy++)
{
    uint32_t rowSizeInBytes = width * 3;
    unsigned char *pDest = &pBuffer[yy * strideInBytes];
    unsigned char *pSrc = &pData[yy * rowSizeInBytes];

    memcpy(pDest, pSrc, rowSizeInBytes);
}

rawBMP->pSrc = pBuffer;
rawBMP->width = width;
rawBMP->height = height;
rawBMP->stride = strideInBytes;
```